# How do I memoize the value emitted by a Single?

Tags: java, rx-java2, memoization, reactivex

Say I have an expensive calculation that creates an object. I want to give the caller some flexibility as to where that happens, with `subscribeOn()`. But I also don't want to make that calculation more than once, because of side effects (e.g. the object is backed by some external data store).

I can write

```
MyObject myObject = MyObject.createExpensively(params);
return Single.just(myObject);
```

but this does the expensive work on the calling thread.

I can write

```
Callable<MyObject> callable = () -> MyObject.createExpensively(params);
return Single.fromCallable(callable);
```

but this will invoke `createExpensively()` (with side effects) once *per subscription*, which isn't what I want if there are multiple subscribers.

If I want to ensure that `createExpensively()` is only called once, and its side effects only occur once, what's the pattern I'm looking for here?

Comment: Have you looked at [Single.cache()](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Single.html#cache--)?

Comment: Singleton pattern?

Comment: @akarnokd How would that work -- `Single.fromCallable(c).cache()`? If so, make it an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: @tolpp No, it's not a singleton because there can be different objects created depending on parameters. I'll edit the question to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `Single.cache()`:

```
Single.fromCallable(() -> MyObject.createExpensively(params)).cache();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Single.fromCallable(() -> MyObject.createExpensively(params)).cache();
```

cache() -> Stores the success value or exception from the current Single and replays it to late SingleObservers. Please have a look [here](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/Single.html#cache--) for more info.

Comment: Please add description , how this will solve the problem.